# R equivalent to SQL query - sum of integer column where date column between parameters

Tags: r, sqldf

Hi there I'm trying to obtain a sum of an integer column where the date given in a separate column is between given parameters.

The following SQL query does what I want, however the query is far too slow in sqldf so I need to find an R equivalent. The data is of hospital episodes where the Stay column indicates number of days spent in hospital for that episode. The df table contains the Index and EndDate for each patient (AnonID)

```
SELECT m.*, b.Sum
               FROM df   
               LEFT JOIN
                   (SELECT AnonID, SUM(e.Stay) AS Sum
                   FROM 
                   (SELECT e.*, d.IndexDate, d.EndDate
                   FROM Episodes e
                   LEFT JOIN df d
                   ON e.AnonID=d.AnonID )a
                   WHERE AdmissionDate BETWEEN CAST(a.IndexDate AS datetime2) AND CAST(a.EndDate AS datetime2)
                   GROUP BY AnonID) b
```

Comment: Just to confirm: you have a data.frame with the data loaded in R?

Comment: Yes sorry that's correct

Comment: Can you put some data up? Just a few rows would be enough. I suggest using `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dplyr` library is one of the most used data manipulation packages for R.
In your particular case we need:

- `left_join` for LEFT JOIN
- `filter` for the WHERE clause
- `group_by` for the GROUP BY
- `summarise` (or `summarize`) to compute aggregates such as SUM
- `%>%` for piping, purely aesthetic but it makes the code easier to read

Putting all that together, you should have something like:

```
library(dplyr)
eps_in_range <- episodes %>%
    left_join(df, by="AnonID") %>%
    filter(AdmissionDate >= IndexDate, 
           AdmissionDate <= EndDate) %>%
    group_by(AnonID) %>%
    summarise(stay_sum = sum(Stay))

df %>%
    left_join(eps_in_range)
```

It is hard to make sure this is 100% correct without seeing the data or understanding what you want to achieve. Hopefully this is enough to get you started. There is a lot of `dplyr` resources out there. I suggest you run the pipes one by one to understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks! This appears to be working... I'm also looking to get a count of the number of episodes (i.e. count of the rows that are being summed in this query), I'm not very familiar with dplyr, how would I count these? I still want this to be grouped by AnonID and to be between the Index and End dates

Comment: To count the rows being summarised you should used n() instead of length(Stay) inside the summarise